# Confusion about Nginx folder paths

Tags: nginx, path

I'm writing this here because there seems to be no consistency over this issue online, and I also think there are some standard practices that I'm not aware of, so if someone could enlighten me that would be great.

I'm trying to get a basic nginx config going on MacOS.

my nginx directory (containing my nginx.conf) is at:

/usr/local/etc/nginx

Meanwhile the index.html file I want to serve is at:

/usr/local/var/www/index.html

These are the directory paths that homebrew gave me when it installed Nginx.

My nginx conf looks like this:

```
  3 events { 
  4     worker_connections  1024; 
  5 } 
  6  
  7 http { 
  8   server { 
  9      
 10     index  index.html index.htm; 
 11  
 12     location / { 
 13       root /var/www; 
 14     } 
 15   } 
 16 }
```

This is what I see on tutorials (including the official nginx one), but I'm confused by why the /var/www in the root isn't a relative path to the root of my machine. I've tried using a relative path, this path and other variations and have continually got a 404. If anyone could a) explain the paths issue and b) tell me where I'm going wrong I'd really appreciate it. I'm reloading nginx with sudo nginx -s reload each time I change the conf.

Comment: What does `nginx -V` give you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your project in /usr/local/var/www/index.html, you should set the nginx root parameter to:

```
root /usr/local/var/www/
```

*root* parameter is meant to be the absolute path of your project folder.
You also should specify which port are you exposing, usually port 80.

Server block could be like this:

```
server {
    listen 80 ;

    server_name     mysite.com ;
    index  index.html index.htm; 

    location / {
        root /usr/local/var/www ;
        # other opts here
    }
}
```